Can't use Plotly.Blazor if BlazorMonaco is installed in my Blazor App
In my Blazor app I'm using Plotly.Blazor for showing some graphs.
I have recently added BlazorMonaco, but once added - Plotly.Blazor stopped working.
In the DevTools console I get the following error:

Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Cannot read properties of
undefined (reading 'newPlot') TypeError: Cannot read properties of
undefined (reading 'newPlot')
at Module.newPlot (https://localhost:5001/_content/Plotly.Blazor/plotly-interop.js:4:19)
at https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3244
...

After exploring a bit:

If I don't reference Monaco's _content/BlazorMonaco/lib/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js   file, Plotly works just fine (but than of course Monaco wont work).
When debugging Plotly's js it seems that window.Plotly is not defined.

My conclusion is that Monaco is probably polluting the global namespace, but I cannot find hard evidence for that...
Any suggestions how I can work around this issue?
Additional information:

BlazorMonaco: Version 3.2.0
Plotly.Blazor: Version 4.3.0


Same with Plotly.Blazor 5.1.1 and BlazorMonaco 3.2/2.1.
When i comment out BlazorMonaco js in index.html Plotly work.
Else Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'newPlot')       TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'newPlot')           at https://localhost:7018/_content/Plotly.Blazor/plotly-interop-5.1.1.js:44:23
